# Trying to combine three individual SELECT statements into one main SELECT statement

Tags: sql, t-sql

Here's the problem.  There are 3 fields in my table which may contain data with an extra quotation appended at the end.  So, I'm trying to run a select statement that will remove this extra character from these fields, IF that extra character exists.  I can write 3 individual queries just fine, and they work, but I'm trying to combine them all into one query.  Here's what I have so far, and I know it's probably incorrect the way I have it:

[image]

Here's the result set that comes back.  Notice that all three columns are `NULL`.  They shouldn't be:

[image]

Here's an individual query that works for one field at a time:

[image]

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Any reason you are doing the subqueries and not joining them to anything?

Comment: No particular reason other than my lack of experience.

Comment: Fair enough. Consider pasting the query into the question instead of the screenshot. Not having to re-type the query may get you additional answers.

Comment: Any reason you are posting your queries as images so that it's not possible to copy and paste them?

Comment: yeah, the server I'm copying from doesn't allow to copy from the server and paste outside of it... unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the WHEREs, as well as the non-correlated subqueries in the select list, and probably simplify it to this...

```
SELECT 
  AID
  , EID
  , STOREID
  , [Language]
  , 'BrandLabel' = CASE WHEN BrandLabel LIKE '%"' 
                         THEN LEFT(BrandLabel, LEN(BrandLabel) -1)
                        ELSE BrandLabel
                   END
  , 'Terms' = CASE WHEN Terms LIKE '%"' 
                         THEN LEFT(Terms, LEN(Terms) -1)
                        ELSE Terms
                   END
  , 'TrackOrderLbl' = CASE WHEN TrackOrderLbl LIKE '%"' 
                         THEN LEFT(TrackOrderLbl, LEN(TrackOrderLbl) -1)
                        ELSE TrackOrderLbl
                   END
FROM parallel_Purchase_Email_Content_OMS WITH (NOLOCK)
```

Comment: This will remove every last character of each of these fields even if the last character shouldn't be removed.  It shouldn't be removed if there's NOT a double quotation at the end, else it should be removed.

Comment: AH, missed that double quotation at the end... looked like a '%'. I'll update.

Comment: That's actually the same solution I came up with as I was trying to figure this out on my own. :)